# Having trouble with an screen recording saved as AVI from Rylstim Screen Recorder

Tags: codec

When I save the recording it produces an AVI. The AVI play perfectly on my computer. When I bring it into Premier though it gets extremely choppy.

The AVI file also won't process on YouTube, I was going to post it for you all to compare.

I'm not sure what could be causing the issue. The Screen Recorder is set to Frame rate of 30. It does have a Codec. I left it on the default Xvid MPEG-4 Codec. Here's a screenshot of the options.

[image]

Would changing to one of the other Codec be a possible solution? Or what other options can I try?

Answer (score 3):

The video may look choppy because of the codec you're using. For fun, I recommend trying out your h.264 variant, x264vfw. I know that h.264 is almost ubiquitously used for internet content.

Playback in premiere is extremely variable when it comes to sequence settings, video preview settings, system preferences (such as scratch discs, and optimizing for memory consumption/performance) and also what type of hardware you have (Nvidia GPUs mercury playback v.s. AMDs OpenCL). I recommend checking out this guide on optimizing your premiere experience: http://blogs.adobe.com/aftereffects/2011/02/optimizing-for-performance-adobe-premiere-pro-and-after-effects.html

Comment: Nope didn't work. Actually even worse in Premiere.

Comment: I was referring to youtube playback, not necessarily premiere. Look into the link I gave you, and also maybe try a different screen capture software for fun. Who knows, maybe the recorder is doing something weird that it isn't making apparent to you.

Comment: Ya, I'm looking into other players and reading that link. If you have any screen recording recommendation for Windows feel free to let me know.

Comment: I personally use FRAPS for all my screen recording needs but that may not be as feature-rich for desktop recording as you like. Bandicam is one that's often used and OBS has a pretty cool utility for recording anything you want. I think of the two I would try OBS first. It has a nice way to specify what you want recorded (be it a window, monitor, or program) and you have a switch for bitrate to control the file size/in exchange for quality.

Comment: I'll look into OBS. Someone else suggested FRAPS but the free version indicates it'll watermark. I may have actually solved this one by trying different Codecs. Microsoft Video 1 works somewhat well.